# IBM.XMS - Set Session.Close timeout

Tags: .net, ibm-mq, xms

**TL;DR** *I'm using IBM.XMS and, when I call `ISession.Close` during a network failure, the method never returns - even if the network is reestablished.*

I'm using IBM.XMS to *read* (that is, *get*) messages from WMQ. During tests, we forced a disconnect from WMQ by removing the network connection between the client and the host. When this happens, any attempt to PUT a message throws an exception which forces a `Close` on `ISession`.

#### Pseudo-code

```
ISession session;
IDestination destination;
IConsumer consumer;

try 
{
    session = GetSession(connection);
    destination = GetDestination(session);
    consumer = GetConsumer(destination);

    while (hasMessage) 
    {
        // process message 
    }
}
catch
{
    session.Close(); // waits forever
}
```

This locks my processing thread *forever*, instead of either timing out after a while and/or throwing an exception (given that there's no network).

I've setup reconnection on the `IConnection` as well:

```
connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);
connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST, $"{hostName}({port})");
connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: What version of XMS .NET are you using?

Comment: Need to know version and Fix Pack of both the client and the QMgr to provide anything more than a guess.